# Locate different patterns in a sequence

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics

If I want to find two different patterns in a single sequence how am I supposed to do
eg:

```
seq="ATGCAAAGGT"
```

the patterns are

```
pattern=c("ATGC","AAGG")
```

How am I supposed to find these two patterns simultaneously in the sequence?

I also want to find the location of these patterns like for example the patterns locations are 1,4 and 5,8.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Do you want to *extract* them, or determine their existence, or *locate* where they are in the sequence?

Comment: what do you mean by "find the location of these patterns"? Do you mean, which row numbers have these patterns?

Comment: Wait, aren't the locations 1,4 and 6,9? Theres an A in between "ATGC" and "AAGG"

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your sequence file is just a vector of sequences:

```
seq.file <- c('ATGCAAAGGT','ATGCTAAGGT','NOTINTHISONE')
```

You can search for both motifs, and then return a true / false vector that identifies if both are present using the following one-liner:

```
grepl('ATGC', seq.file) & grepl('AAGG', seq.file)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Lets say the vector of sequences is a column within data frame `d`, which also contains a column of ID values:

```
id <- c('s1','s2','s3')
d <- data.frame(id,seq.file)
colnames(d) <- c('id','sequence')
```

You can append a column to this data frame, `d`, that identifies whether a given sequence matches with this one-liner:

```
d$match <- grepl('ATGC',d$sequence) & grepl('AAGG', d$sequence)
> print(d)
  id     sequence match
1 s1   ATGCAAAGGT  TRUE
2 s2   ATGCTAAGGT  TRUE
3 s3 NOTINTHISONE FALSE
```

The following for-loop can return a list of the positions of each of the patterns within the sequence:

```
require(stringr)

for(i in 1: length(d$sequence)){
    out <- str_locate_all(d$sequence[i], pattern)
    first    <- c(out[[1]])
    first.o  <- paste(first[1],first[2],sep=',')
    second   <- c(out[[2]])
    second.o <- paste(second[1],second[2], sep=',')
    print(c(first.o, second.o))
}
[1] "1,4" "6,9"
[1] "1,4" "6,9"
[1] "NA,NA" "NA,NA"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `stringr` library to do something like this:

```
seq = "ATGCAAAGGT"
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(seq, 'ATGC|AAGG')
[[1]]
[1] "ATGC" "AAGG"
```

Without knowing more specifically what output you are looking for, this is the best I can provide right now.

Answer (score 1):

How about this using `stringr` to find start and end positions:

```
library(stringr)
seq <- "ATGCAAAGGT"
pattern <- c("ATGC","AAGG")
str_locate_all(seq, pattern)

#[[1]]
#     start end
#[1,]     1   4
#
#[[2]]
#     start end
#[1,]     6   9
```

Comment: Is there any other way to identify patterns other than str_locate_all?

Comment: @shrinirajesh Why not using that?